# Number of diagonals of a concave polygons formula?

Tags: geometry

Does this [formula](https://www.mathopenref.com/polygondiagonal.html) also apply to concave polygons?

[image]

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "distinct diagonal." The expression $n(n-3)/2$ counts the number of ways to select two non-adjacent vertices of any polygon. But in a concave polygon, the lines connecting such pairs may overlap.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, no, and maybe, depending on what you mean by diagonal and distinct.  For a convex polygon of $n$ vertices, you can draw a diagonal by choosing one vertex ($n$ ways), choosing a second vertex that is not the first nor connected to the first ($n-3$ ways), and dividing by $2$ because you can start at either end of the diagonal.  This process works fine for a concave polygon, too, so yes.  Some of the diagonals are outside the polygon, so if you require a diagonal to lie within the polygon, no.  You can create a concave polygon so that more than two noncontiguous vertices are on a line.  If you do, some of the diagonals will overlap, which may violate your definition of distinct, so maybe.

Answer (score 1):

If you count all the diagonals, including the ones that lie outside the polygon, yes.

EXCEPT that, if you have enough points and enough ingenuity, you can arrange the points of the polygon so that some diagonal somewhere will lie directly on top of some other diagonal.  In that case, do you have *two* diagonals, with one "hidden", or do you have *one* diagonal that does "double duty" in connecting, not two, but three or more points?  That's a question of definition and I'm not sure what the standard answer is.